# how to add a http header to a soaprequest in java

Tags: java, soap, header, apache-axis

I try to connect to a Yahoo webservice. I generated the classes by axis2. The problem I am facing right now is, that the webservice requires a specific key value pair in the header and I am absolutely not able, to do so. I searched the web and found different possibilities - none of them worked for me. The most promissing was the post nearly at the end of [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/489196/Web-Services/java/Axis-Http-Header), were Claude Coulombe sugested to change the code of the generated stub, but this failed as well. Can anybody show me a way how to solve this issue?

**Edit**

The suggested way using Options produced the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Address information does not exist in the Endpoint Reference (EPR).The system cannot infer the transport mechanism.
```

Here is my code:

```
val stub = new IndexToolsApiServiceStub("https://api.web.analytics.yahoo.com/IndexTools/services/IndexToolsApiV3")

val client = stub._getServiceClient
val options = new Options
val list = new ArrayList[Header]()
val header = new Header
header.setName("YWA_API_TOKEN")
header.setValue("NOTtheREALvalue")
list.add(header)
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, list)
client.setOptions(options)
stub._setServiceClient(client)
```

Comment: I assume your question is about HTTP headers (not HTML). You may want to correct the typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem two months ago. You are not able to set a customized header  with Axis2. So I fell back to the older Axisversion, where you can do it. Setting the Http-header by yourself is no good practice and mostly unneccesary. On top it is not a part of the SOAP-specification. That is the reason why you cannot do it with Axis2.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to use `Axis2`'s [Options](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Options.html):

```
// Create an instance of org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient
ServiceClient client = ...

// Create an instance of org.apache.axis2.client.Options
Options options = new Options();

List list = new ArrayList();

// Create an instance of org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header
Header header = new Header();

// Http header. Name : user, Value : admin
header.setName("user");
header.setValue("admin");

list.add(header);
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, list);

client.setOptions(options);
```

Here's the [reference](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/02/adding-custom-http-headers-via-axis2.html) for that code.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if you want to add HTTP headers to your SOAP request or response. either ways you should work with MessageContext.
Supposed that msgContext is your Axis2 request/response Message Context object (org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext), below code will do the trick and using it, you can add HTTP headers.

```
`//Instantiate an Options object from org.apache.axis2.client.Options
 Options options = new Options();
 //Instantiate an ArrayList of type NamedValue from org.apache.axis2.context.NamedValue
 List<NamedValue> namedValuePairs = new ArrayList<NamedValue>();
 //Add as much as headers you want using below code
 namedValuePairs.add(new NamedValue("sample", "value"));
 //Finally add namedValuePairs to options, and add options to msgContext
 options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, namedValuePairs);
 msgContext.setOptions(options);`
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you just have to retrieve the options reference from the `ServiceClient` instead of replacing the options object. Then add the properties you want:

```
ServiceClient sc = awst._getServiceClient();
Options ops = sc.getOptions();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution -

```
    MyStub stub = new MyStub();
    ServiceClient serviceClient = stub._getServiceClient();
    Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();
    List<NamedValue> namedValuePairs = new ArrayList<NamedValue>();
    namedValuePairs.add(new NamedValue("Authorization", "Basic JSDFANSKMSLAWQEINCCAKNASKNAS2371BASCKA="));
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, namedValuePairs);
```

Just need to set an additional property on options, don't create a new option variable as below, that didn't help in my case.

```
Options options = new Options();
```

Also, setting `HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE` directly doesn't work(as set below)

```
clientOptions.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem the solution is that of Barbiturica:
add header option without

```
   // Create an instance of org.apache.axis2.client.Options
Options options = new Options();
```

this page is missleading: [reference](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/02/adding-custom-http-headers-via-axis2.html)